# googlecloudpubsub:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub, sbt-assembly

I am facing this issue when trying to run a google cloud subscriber within a scala sbt project on local windows environment. The versions used are as follows:

```
java : 1.8.0_171"

scala : 2.11.8
```

below are the versions of sbt library dependencies:

```
"com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-pubsub" % "1.108.1",

"com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-shared-dependencies" % "0.8.6" pomOnly(),

"com.google.api.grpc" % "grpc-google-cloud-pubsub-v1" % "1.90.1",

"io.grpc" % "grpc-all" % "1.30.2"
```

The deployment is done by running a fat JAR in nohup build using sbt assembly plugin.

This is the error log which I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the service InnerService [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.checkCurrentState(AbstractService.java:366)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.awaitRunning(AbstractService.java:302)
        at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService.awaitRunning(AbstractApiService.java:96)
        at services.externalservices.pubsub.GoogleCloudSubscriber$class.subscribeAsyncExample(GoogleCloudSubscriber.scala:89)
        at services.externalservices.pubsub.GoogleCloudSubscriber$class.initialise(GoogleCloudSubscriber.scala:37)
        at services.externalservices.pubsub.GoogleCloudSubscriberImpl.initialise(GoogleCloudSubscriber.scala:95)
        at services.externalservices.pubsub.GoogleCloudSubscriber$class.$init$(GoogleCloudSubscriber.scala:27)
        at services.externalservices.pubsub.GoogleCloudSubscriberImpl.<init>(GoogleCloudSubscriber.scala:95)
        at services.externalservices.pubsub.GoogleCloudSubscriberImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$a4a053ae.newInstance(<generated>)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory    .get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:233)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:144)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:93)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:414)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:513)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:314)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1600(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:71)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:210)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:217)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:200)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:156)
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:272)
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.doStart(Subscriber.java:273)
        at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService$InnerService.doStart(AbstractApiService.java:148)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAsync(AbstractService.java:248)
        at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiService.startAsync(AbstractApiService.java:120)
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber.startAsync(Subscriber.java:265)
```

However, the same subscriber works as expected when running the application in foreground using **sbt run** command.

Comment: You may need to update your Java version to Java 8u252 or Java 11. This GitHub discussion thread may be relevant: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5369

Comment: Hello, have you added sbt-assembly as a dependency in `project/plugins.sbt` as explained [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#using-published-plugin)?